# Add a colourful image as the right bar button item in a navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I add a right navigation bar item that has a coloured background image:

```
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "avatar")!,
                                  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, 
                                  target: self,     
                                  action: #selector(self.rightNavBarItemAction))

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

Instead of having the image as the background of the button (in colours), I get a white placeholder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update the image's rendering mode to 
`UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal`.

**Swift 4.2:**

```
let img = UIImage(named: "avatar")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: img,
                                      style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.Plain,
                                      target: self,
                                      action: #selector(self.rightNavBarItemAction))
```

**Swift 4:**

```
let img = UIImage(named: "avatar")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: img,
                                      style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                                      target: self,
                                      action: #selector(self.rightNavBarItemAction))
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let img = UIImage(named: "avatar")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: img,
                                      style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                                      target: self,
                                      action: #selector(self.rightNavBarItemAction))
```

Alternatively you can set a custom view as in Vladimir's answer.

Comment: for Swift 4.2 UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you need a button `UIButton`, set the image of that button and then assigned it as the custom view if your `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 51, 31)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "avatar"), forState: .Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.rightNavBarItemAction)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
barButton.customView = button
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```